# recycler view не работает скролл

Tags: android, recyclerview

Добрый день, столкнулся с проблемой. Тестировал приложение ранее на genymotion (nexus 4 android api 16), samsung gs iv (api 21), samsung gs iii (api 16), nexus 9 (api 23). На каждом устройстве все работает нормально, решил запустить на попавшем в руки самсунге gt-i8262 (api 16), почему то не работает скролл во всех RecyclerView. Разметки разные, в большинстве разметок корневой и единственный элемент это recyclerview, не вижу вообще возможностей проблемы, тем не менее скролл не работает. Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Для примера привожу код, разметка такая

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Фрагмент, в котором используется разметка (выбрал самый не большой,  котором есть все, и адаптер, и холдер и управление ресайклером).

```
public class NewsFragment extends Fragment {

    int currentLastArticle = 0;
    int count;
    ArrayList<Article> news = new ArrayList<>();

    View view;
    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);

        rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.addItemDecoration(new Divider(getActivity()));
        rv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerScrollListener(llm) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                new GetNewsTask().execute(20, currentLastArticle+=20);
            }
        });

        new GetNewsTask().execute(20, currentLastArticle);

        return view;
    }

    class NewsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public NewsRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new NewsVH(inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ((NewsVH)holder).set(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return news.size();
        }

        private class NewsVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            Text title;
            Text time;
            ImageView image;
            View itemView;

            public NewsVH(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.itemView = itemView;
                itemView.setPadding(
                        Decorator.getWidthBasedOnIPhone640(8),
                        Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(8),
                        Decorator.getWidthBasedOnIPhone640(8),
                        Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(8)
                );
                init(itemView);
            }

            private void init(View view) {
                title = (Text) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(24));
                Decorator.setMargins(title, 0, 8, 0, 0);
                time = (Text) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
                time.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(20));
                time.setTextStyle(font.font133l);
                image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
                image.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                Decorator.setSquareSizeAndMargins(image, 176, 0, 0, 8, 8);
            }

            public void set(final int position) {
                Article article = news.get(position);
                title.setText(article.title());
                time.setText(article.time());
                String image = article.files().length == 0 ? "null" : article.files()[0].url480();
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(image, this.image, Decorator.getImageOptions(svg.zelen.drawable()));
                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ArticleFragment fragment = new ArticleFragment();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putParcelable(getString(R.string.article), news.get(position));
                        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .beginTransaction()
                                .addToBackStack(Flags.CATALOG_BACKSTACK)
                                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName())
                                .commit();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    class GetNewsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, JSONArray> {

        int lowTreshold;
        int highTreshold;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ((ProgressSwitcher)activity).showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            lowTreshold = params[1];
            highTreshold = params[0];

            String newsString = Web.httpGet(
                    Web.url.domain +
                            Web.url.content +
                            "/" +
                            highTreshold +
                            "/" +
                            lowTreshold
            );

            JSONArray jNewsArray = new JSONArray();

            try {
                JSONObject jNews = new JSONObject(newsString);
                jNewsArray = jNews.getJSONArray("content");
                count = jNews.getInt("count");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return jNewsArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jArray) {
            ((ProgressSwitcher)activity).hideProgress();
            int length = jArray.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                try {
                    news.add(new Article(jArray.getJSONObject(i)));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (rv.getAdapter() == null) {
                rv.setAdapter(new NewsRecyclerAdapter(activity));
            } else {
                rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Вчера ночью порешал проблему. Проблема была в вымученном дизайне и давней попытке решить один баг. У меня есть DrawerLayout, в котором при нажатии на итемы NavigationDrawer открываются фрагменты. В одном из фрагментов я должен был реализовать табы (фрагмент - страинца продукта, в табах комментарии, либо описание продукта), содержимое таба открывалось в отдельном контейнере. Как то раз решая баг я дошел до того, что в DrawerLayout поместил основной контейнер для фрагментов и контейнер для табов в скроллвью, высоту которого (и фрагмента в нем) задавал жестко и динамически (исходя из размеров девайса), чтобы скроллвью не скроллился кроме того единственного случая, когда мы видим содержимое таба. В результате на последнем самсунге я поймал баг той функции, которая считала высоту скроллвью, потому что достаточно было одного лишнего пикселя, чтобы он стал свободно болтаться, и получил у себя в приложении скроллящиеся View (RecyclerView) внутри сввободно плавающего ScrollView, что привело к тому, что экран вообще не реагироввал на мои жесты. В итоге я убрал все касающееся страницы продукта в разметку страницы продукта, и получил свою порцию счастья :) сем спасибо за участие и советы, а мне минус в карму, за то, что попытался вырвать задачу из контекста, который важен для её понимания.

Comment: Вы там `ViewPager` не используете с анимацией случайно?

Comment: Скажем так, не работают все ресайклеры в приложении, а наполнение у них разное. В одном действительно есть ViewFlipper с анимацией, но это только в одном. И при этом на других девайсах то скролл работает. Нашел сегодня Yota SDK и поставил эмулятор, такая же фигня с ним, т.е. даже на колесо мыши не отзывается.

Comment: @iamthevoid получается, что у вас не работает вызов `onLoadMore()`? Пробовали туда ставить логгер и смотреть что там происходит?

Comment: Нет, этот метод отрабатывает прекрасно. Я привел разметку для примера, но проблема была и в других разметках, не связанных с onLoadMore и постепенной подгрузкой. Впрочем ответ найден, в любом случчае спасбо Вам за проявленное внимание

Comment: @iamthevoid, мне, конечно, приятно +75 репы получить, но верно ли я понял, что вы нашли ответ на свою проблему и он не тот, за коий я награду получил? Если да, то было бы хорошо, если бы вы в своём ответе его написали - это может помочь людям  со схожей проблемой)

Comment: Юрий, в общем ответ описан в вопросе, Если кому то будут нужны подробности, то он всегда смоет оживить вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432632/3212712) на некоторых девайсах система несколько изменена и косячит. Решить сие можно грязным хаком - переопределением "неработающего" виджета и изменения некоторых методов. В частности, в вопросе по ссылке в логах была ошибка в методе `scrollTo()`. Засим посмотрите как по ссылке изменили этого метод, может помочь. Кратко - в методе не вызывают `super.onScrollTo()`

Comment: Нет, не помогло. Тут что то другое. Самое интересное, что скроллвью или GestureDetectorы работают везде адекватно, а вот Recycler нет

Comment: @iamthevoid, а в логи ничего не выдаёт?..

Comment: Нет, не выдает :(

Comment: @iamthevoid если это решение не помогло, то лучше не ставить галочку на ответе, т.к. она как раз означает, что именно это решение сработало.